# What is this called: myVar = value1 or value2

Tags: python, ternary-operator

I've seen this kind of ternary assignment called and I was wondering if it had a specific name:

```
value1 = None
value2 = 'real value'
myVar = value1 or value2

// at this point the value of myVar is 'real value'
```

Comment: I don't know that this is "ternary" assignment, but rather "defined or" perhaps?

Comment: @squiguy, this is truly called a ternary assignment in Python, since that's how it was used before the `... if ... else ...` [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) was added in Python 2.5.

Comment: @MarkRansom Ah, I am more Perl inclined and user to seeing `$var //= $other`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs call that a [boolean operation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).  The value of `value1 or value2` is just a feature of the language.

In C and C-inspired languages there is a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a).  The effect of this operator is better called a "conditional expression".  Python has a conditional expression, too:

```
myVar = value1 if value1 else value2
```

I prefer using the conditional expression to the boolean operators in this kind of situation.  The effect of `myVar = value1 or value2` is not obvious to someone who isn't fluent in Python.

Comment: In his case `None == False` too. As would `0`, `null` and `void` probably be too.

Comment: `None != False` and `None != 0`, in Python 2.7 at least.  `bool(None) == False`, thought.  There is no `null` or `void` in Python.

Comment: If you're downvoting this answer, consider adding a better answer or at least a comment.

Comment: Yet; the `None` seems to have triggered `value2`. Is there an inconstancy? I up-voted it when you just posted it already; so it's not me :)

Comment: It's worth noting that the `or` operator doesn't work the same as it does in C or C++, as it returns one of the two values rather than a boolean result.

Comment: @Allendar: whether `value2` is returned by `value1 or value2` expression depends on "truthiness" of `value1`: `bool(None) == bool(0) == bool(0.0) == bool([]) == bool('') == bool(False) == False == etc`. See [truth testing procedure](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth)